# Word add-in toolbar problem

Tags: c#, vsto, word-2003

I am building a word2k3 add-in and i'm creating a new toolbar containing the relevant buttons. All seems to work fine except, depending on who is viewing the active document, certain buttons must be enabled/disabled. This is not a problem as I simply set the button.enabled to true/false and it does the trick.

My problem is that after enabling/disabling these buttons a couple of times, I suddenly get an Hresult error. I tried googling the error and it says something about the button not being there or something. 
The exact exception is the following: {"Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A01A8"} System.SystemException {System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException}

I'm utterly confused about this issue since it occurs at random times and I just cant figure out what might cause it.

p.s.: I also have buttons on the menu bar and this problem never occurs there, only on the toolbar.

cheers

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like somehow you're loosing the reference to the buttons. Are they in global vars? Could those vars be being cleared (maybe by event code you've forgotten about)?